# Force Boost to use C++11 Threads

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, cmake

I am trying to compile the Boost ASIO examples using CMake on Ubuntu 13.04 with GCC 4.73.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_client.cpp

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

With the following CMake File:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-std=c++11)
project(server)

find_package( Boost 1.53.0 REQUIRED system)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )

add_executable( server server.cpp )
target_link_libraries(server ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )

add_executable( client client.cpp )
target_link_libraries(client ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

The project should be using C++11 and be platform independent. When compiling using the CMakefile I get something like

```
undefined reference to `pthread_join'
```

My colleague can compile exactly the same Makefile without any problems.

The question: Is there any way to force CMake or Boost not to use PThreads but the C++11 Threads to stay platform independent?

EDIT: The server compiles without problems while only the client has problems.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure C++11 doesn't have its own thread implementation. It's a wrapper around pthread or whatever is appropriate to the platform. I'm sure Boost handles the portability issues.

Comment: @FredLarson is correct, C++11 _can't_ have it's own thread implementation, at some point is has to rely on the threading model that the underlying operating system provides, in the case of Linux, that is `pthread`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So you have any clue, why it works at my colleagues Linux machine with the same make file? Maybe his compiler automatically links pthread?

Comment: If it's the same compiler, with the same arguments, then it should be the same.  So, the first thing I would do is to verify that you're both invoking the compiler with the same arguments.  There is a way to get cmake to output the commands it is executing.  I would use that and compare.

Comment: You'll need to give the linker a `-pthread` argument. (I don't know how CMake works, but I'm sure there must be a simple way to do that).

Comment: You may use find_package(Threads REQUIRED) as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395309/cmake-and-threads

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to force CMake or Boost not to use PThreads but the C++11 Threads to stay platform independent?

No, both Boost.Threads and GCC's C++ threads library are implemented as a fairly thin layer over Pthreads.

> So you have any clue, why it works at my colleagues Linux machine with the same make file? Maybe his compiler automatically links pthread?

It's possible to configure GCC with `--enable-libstdcxx-time=rt` which causes the C++ standard library to be linked to `librt` and `libpthread`. That means you don't need to link with `-pthread`, so it's possible your colleague is using GCC configured like that.  That configuration option is not the default because automatically linking to `libpthread.so` negatively affects performance of single-threaded programs that use some parts of the C++ standard library.