# Cmake import -lpthread and others

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, c++14, clang++

Maybe its a stupid question but I have an program that I need -lmysqlcppconn -lreadline and -lpthread.

I'm using the cmake to generate the makefile for that I resolve use :

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1y -lmysqlcppconn -lreadline -lpthread")
...(other command most likely irrelevant)

add_executable(name ${SOURCES} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAG})
```

but I received the follow warning when I execute the makefile :

```
clang: warning: -lmysqlcppconn: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: -lreadline: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: -lpthread: 'linker' input unused
```

Exists a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is for compiler flags (with CMake-generated make files compilation and linking are separate steps). To link you need something like

```
target_link_libraries(name mysqlcppconn)
target_link_libraries(name readline)
target_link_libraries(name pthread)
```

For threading library a better way is to follow the process explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5402608/267482)

Comment: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "eyeTyou" which is not built by
  this project. I tryed that before but I don't know to link this libraries

Comment: Sorry , my error I don't expected that I needed to cal target_link_libraries(...) after the add_executable(...) that works

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Not even calling it after add_executable.

Comment: I had a problem with "undefined reference to `get_driver_instance'", adding the linker flags in other possible ways did not help, but finally adding it this way resolved the problem.