# What is the proper use of CMake FindThreads with modern C++?

Tags: c++11, cmake

The source for the CMake (https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindThreads.cmake) claims the following about the "FindThreads" functionality:

> This module is not needed for C++11 and later if threading is done using
>   `std::thread` from the standard library.

But if I follow this advice (on my Mint18 x86_64 system, gcc8, CMake 3.13.2) I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/prism-esm-dummy.dir/src/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If the module is exercised (as best I could figure using other SO articles and previously given advice):

```
set (THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package (Threads REQUIRED)

add_executable(my_app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (my_app Threads::Threads)
```

... the result is the same.

`THREADS_FOUND` is `true` and `CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS_INIT` is `1`, but i get no `-pthread` under compile, or a `-lpthread` during link.  I checked a number of other variables mentioned in the module, and all I tried were not set.

Is there a correct way to do this?  Or should I just use the normal flags and move on with my life?

Comment: Are you using `pthread_*` APIs directly in your code?

Comment: No. I'm using std::thread.

Answer (score 6):

```
find_package( Threads )
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} )
```

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5402608/10838321

Comment: Worked perfectly. This save me a lot of time. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

I try to give a more complete answer, since I struggled a bit implementing what was suggested above

Create a new folder

`mkdir test_project`
`cd test_project`

First of all you will need to create a `test.cpp` with:

`touch test.cpp`

and then paste in the file the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

in your CMakeLists.txt you should have something like the following:

```
project("test_proj")
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.4) # this depends on what you are testing
find_package(Threads)
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries( test ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} )
```

I hope this answer helps someone with the same problem.